# copying dictionary vs adding element to reconstruct dicionary

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

In python, I need to reconstruct a dictionary from an existing dictionary. The number of dictionary elements are around 5. I can make the new dictionary with the five elements or I can copy the existing dictionary.

Which method is faster between copying and making new one?

(I need to put this into for loop so it might big difference at the end.)

Example code:

```
orig = {'pid': 12345, 'name': 'steven king', 'country': 'usa', 'sex': 'M', 'company': 'MS'}

for _ in range(5000):

    copy1 = orig.copy()

    newone = {}
    newone['pid'] = 12345
    newone['name'] = 'steven king', 
    newone['country']= 'usa' 
    newone['sex'] = 'M'
    newone['company] = 'MS'
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you only trying to make copies or extract certain elements from each dict?

Comment: [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#:~:text=This%20module%20provides%20a%20simple,traps%20for%20measuring%20execution%20times.) and see.

Comment: @Jab I need to add new elements inside for loop to the new dictionary. And save all the dictionaries.

Comment: Have you tried timing it and seeing for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more way using `argument unpacking`

```
newone = {**orig}
```

Which you can also add new variables in that line:

```
newone = {**orig, 'newval': 'test'}
```

But from my simple tests the `copy` method seems to be the fastest:

```
from timeit import timeit

orig = {'pid': 12345, 'name': 'steven king', 'country': 'usa', 'sex': 'M', 'company': 'MS'}

def f1():
  newone = orig.copy()
  newone['newval'] = 'test'

def f2():
  newone = {}
  newone['pid'] = 12345
  newone['name'] = 'steven king', 
  newone['country']= 'usa' 
  newone['sex'] = 'M'
  newone['company'] = 'MS'
  newone['newval'] = 'test'

def f3():
  newone = {**orig, 'newval': 'test'}


print(timeit(f1))
print(timeit(f2))
print(timeit(f3))
```

Results:

```
1.4525865920004435
1.858240751986159
1.4954008519998752
```

Try here: https://repl.it/repls/NeglectedOrneryBash